# Character encoding in HTML

Tags: html, character-encoding

I have a problem with character encoding. This code will not show Danish letters æøå:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/reset.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/css3buttons.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="outerframe">
        <div class="title">Familien intra</div>
        <div class="navigation"></div>

        <div class="contentframe">
            <div class="tab default" data-title="Oversigt">
                <iframe style="float:right;margin:0px 0px 20px 20px;" src="https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?showTitle=0&amp;showNav=0&amp;showPrint=0&amp;showTz=0&amp;mode=AGENDA&amp;height=400&amp;wkst=2&amp;hl=da&amp;bgcolor=%23ffffff&amp;src=o4240er9b5q8rk83f7p2rbgoj0%40group.calendar.google.com&amp;color=%23B1365F&amp;ctz=Europe%2FCopenhagen" style=" border-width:0 " width="400" height="400" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
                <h2>Links</h2>
                <ul class="nobullet">
                    <li><a href="https://spreadsheets.google.com/ccc?key=0AkVjiPXeK_wXdEJ0RUhQaHZQZ2hXUDVxMHR5WlpHd2c&hl=en_GB#gid=11" class="imgbullet" style="background-image:url(http://www.zmetro.com/graphics/google20x20.jpg)" target="_blank">Indkøbslisten</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/home.php?sk=group_129199637150329&ap=1" class="imgbullet" style="background-image:url(http://www.golden-bound.com/home_page_extras/images/Facebook_icon_20x20.jpg);" target="_blank">Familiens Facebook-gruppe</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I simply don't see what the problem is. Instead of showing æøå, it replaces them with upside down question marks...

Comment: Oh, I've tried with utf-8 as well. Same problem, but the question marks are not upside down. :D

Comment: What browser are you using? Firefox?

Comment: @Reinderien i'm using IE and Firefox, problem is not about the browser...but the fact that the generated page includes that question mark..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume the encoding is implemented correctly, as [this Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML) page states the same one.

I've seen such a thing happen before. The solution for me was to save the file itself as an UTF-8 or UTF-16 file. I once opened the file in Notepad and it got saved as an ANSI file which doesn't support these Unicode characters.
Saving it as a different kind of file could help, sometimes. Try out multiple, as not all will give the same kind of results.

Comment: MY GOD! Worked instantly. You're a genius. Thanks! :) Will accept in a few minutes.

Answer (score 2):

I tested the contents of your file. Both ISO-8859-1 and UTF-8 should work fine.

**The problem is most likely being caused by having the file saved in your local character set instead of the one that should be displayed to the end user.**

Make sure you save the actual file in the same character encoding as the one that you want to display to the end user (ISO-8859-1 or UTF-8), this will make the difference. Most editors include some kind of option for this.

As a fallback, you could use **character references**:

```
æ = &aelig;
ø = &oslash;
å = &aring;
```

See also [this reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/sgml/entities.html).